# Get value from selected databound listbox item

Tags: c#, xaml, data-binding, uwp, listbox

I really don't know how to ask this question, but this is what I am trying to achieve. I have a list box with this code:

```
<ListBox 
    x:Name="lb"
    Margin="0,0,0,100"
    Background="#212B34"
    BorderThickness="0"
    Padding="0"
    SelectionChanged="lb_SelectionChanged">

    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"></Setter>
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0,8,0,8"></Setter>
        </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid Height="152" BorderThickness="10,0,0,0" BorderBrush="#2E66AA" Background="#161C22" Padding="8,8,8,8">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="30"></RowDefinition>
                    <RowDefinition Height="25"></RowDefinition>
                    <RowDefinition Height="25"></RowDefinition>
                    <RowDefinition Height="60"></RowDefinition>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="4*"></ColumnDefinition>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"></ColumnDefinition>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <TextBlock Foreground="#2E66AA" Text="{Binding Location}" FontSize="18" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"></TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Foreground="White" Text="{Binding Description}" FontSize="12" Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="3" Grid.Column="0" TextTrimming="WordEllipsis" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" TextWrapping="Wrap"></TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Foreground="White" Text="{Binding Date}" FontSize="18" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" TextAlignment="Right"></TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Foreground="White" Text="{Binding Time}" FontSize="18" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" TextAlignment="Right"></TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Foreground="#2E66AA" FontSize="24" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" TextAlignment="Right">
                    <Run Text="$ "/>
                    <Run Text="{Binding Price}"/>
                    <Run Text=";"/>
                </TextBlock>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

And use Azure App Service for my database. I bind the data to the listbox using itemsource:

```
private async void loadEvents_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    IMobileServiceTable<eventTable> eventList = App.MobileService.GetTable<eventTable>();

    
    MobileServiceCollection<eventTable, eventTable> events = await eventList
        .Where(ProductTable => ProductTable.id != "")
        .ToCollectionAsync();

    lb.ItemsSource = events;

}
```

What I want to do is when a user selects a listbox item he needs to be redirected to a new page. But on this new page I need the id of the event (row in the database). So I can use this id to retrieve all further information of the event.

Maybe I need to bind the id to the listboxitem by using {Binding id} but what do I bind it to? A textblock which I can make invisible? And if I bind it to something how do I retrieve it?

This is what I use to redirect the user to a new page:

```
private void lb_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(eventPage));
}
```

If there is a different way to get al information about the selected event please tell.

I would really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get the `SelectedItem` from `lb.SelectedItem` and typecast to its corresponding class. From that, you can get the selected item's Ip. Now pass this value as the second parameter to `Frame.Navigate`.

```
private void lb_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(eventPage), (eventTable)lb.SelectedItem);
}
```

To get this value on the next page

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnNavigatedTo(e);

    var selectedItem = (eventTable)e.Parameter;
}
```

Comment: Okay using selectedItem.id works thank you so much. But is selectedItem is a object?

Comment: "is selectedItem is a object?" - yes